# Android pass intent to previous Activity

Tags: android

I want to send some data to previous Activity. But it does not work.

here i need to send some data .

```
 btnSaveRecord = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSaveRecord);
        btnSaveRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Record_Audio.this , AddPost.class);
                intent.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", newAudioFile);

                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }
        });
```

Here is my previous Activity

```
 if (savedInstanceState == null)
        {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if(extras == null)
            {
                newString= null;
                Log.e("111"," = "+newString);
            }
            else
            {
                newString= extras.getString("STRING_I_NEED");
                Log.e("222"," = "+newString);
            }
        } else
        {
            newString= (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("STRING_I_NEED");
            Log.e("333"," = "+newString);
        }
```

What code do i need here , I don't understand why not work.

Comment: implement `onActivityResult()` in your first activity.

Answer (score 2):

Try [getting the result from an activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html).

To sum up the article:

```
static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;  // The request code
...
private void itemClicked() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    // Add any data that you wish to send
    intent.putExtra("DATA", "value");
    startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

In your second activity, receive the data you wish to modify:

String valueToChange = getIntent().getExtras().getString("DATA");

Then put it in an Edit text or whatever you want to do with it, when you are done set it as the result bundle.

```
// Create the result Intent
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("RESULT", "YourNewString");
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

In your first activity, override `onActivityResult` to get the value.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request it is that we're responding to
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             String newString = data.getExtras().getString("RESULT");
         }
    }
}
```

You may also want to send through the items position in the array so that you can update it.

Answer (score 0):

use this to send data to previous activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("done", true);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
FiltersActivity.this.finish();
```

and then in previous activity receive like this

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        Log.e("Codes for result ", "requestCode = " + requestCode + " resultCode = " + resultCode);

        switch (requestCode) {

            case SHARE_PHOTO:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Boolean isDoneSharing = data.getBooleanExtra("done", false);

                }

        }
    }
```